# How do I align my label and input element contents on separate lines while maintaining centered alignments?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align my form contents so that each label falls on a separate line and the input content within the label falls in separate lines after the label element. Please help. I included an image link and my code in this question.

I would like my label to be displayed above the input elements, the input elements to have centered content (for example: radio type inputs to be aligned perfectly centered with their relative text description. If I have "male" as an option for a radio, I would like the input button itself to be aligned centered and even with the words "male").

[image: What I am trying to get it to look like]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.form-group {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

label {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="radio"],
label {
  align-items: center;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
    <h1 id="title">Studentas Survey Form</h1>
    <p id="description">Thank you for taking time to complete this survey</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <form id="survey-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label id="name-label">Enter your name
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required></input>
        </label>

        <label id="email-label">Enter your Email 
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required></input>
        </label>

        <label id="number-label">Enter your age 
        <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="99" placeholder="Age" required></input>
        </label>

        <label>Favorite subject?
          <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
            <option value="1">History</option>
            <option value="2">Math</option>
            <option value="3">Science</option>
            <option value="4">English</option>
          </select>
        <label>

        <label>What is your gender?
          <input type="radio" name="gender" required>Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" required>Female</label>
        </label>

        <label>What do you like about school?
          <input type="checkbox" value="lunch" required>Lunch Time</input>
          <input type="checkbox" value="social" required>Social Interaction</input>
          <input type="checkbox" value="work" required>Course Work</input>
          <input type="checkbox" value="home" required>Going Home</input>
        </label>

        <label>What are your thoughts on this survey?
          <textarea></textarea>
        </label>
        <input type="submit"></input>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your class names and your screenshot seem to indicate the use of a library like Bootstrap. If that's the case, please mention it and tag accordingly.

Comment: The screenshot does not show things being center-aligned (for instance, the radio buttons in that image are left-aligned, with the radio button and label on the same line, not on separate lines). If the image is not representative of what you want, I would remove it as you are likely to get answers with CSS to get the code given to look like the image given...

Comment: Generally speaking, the easiest way to do what you're asking is if the `label` element is separate from the form element it labels, using the `for` attribute to associate it with the element. By the way, the HTML for the checkboxes and radio buttons you have is invalid; `input` is an empty element; it cannot have text within it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out!

```
.Your-choosen-label
{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction:column;
}
```

Comment: If you want your radio type inputs to be in one line put all of them in a div or something and add the `flex-direction:row` insted of `flex-direction:column` to the div's style also remove the paddings to put your radio and its text near each other